# The Pyzmq19.0.2 version cannot be installed

Tags: python, pyzmq

The failure of Jupyter may be due to the PyZMQ version, which is 22.3.0 by default

However, 19.0.2 cannot be installed after uninstalling the current version

What to do

Comment: Can you share the actual error message which you got?

Comment: There's lots of context missing from your question. Start by searching the bug reports of the software you're trying to install. If that doesn't help, explain the steps you took and provide the output you received. As a new user here, also read [ask] and take the [tour].